# error Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am trying to build a string representation for the show function of a typeclass representing a polynomial. I keep getting type errors of a mismatch from 'Char' to '[Char]', but from my understanding haskell's "append" function should be able to concatenate a Char to a string/[Char]. I don't understand where the problem lies, or where to look for a solution based on the errors I receive. here is the faulty code:

```
newtype Poly a = P [a]

instance (Num a, Show a) => Show (Poly a) where
    show p = ["" : form (p !! i) i | i <- [l,(l-1)..0]]
        where
            l = length p
            form e i 
                | i == 0 = elem
                | i == 1 = elem ++ "x + "
                | otherwise = elem ++ "x^" ++ (show i) ++ " + "
                    where elem = show e
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I can see some problems already, but you really should post the definition of `Poly`.

Comment: Also, you should start small and work your way up. Can you write the `form` function at the top level (not in a `where` clause), with its own type signature? Once you've done that, you can build up a little...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write

> from my understanding haskell's "append" function should be able to concatenate a Char to a string/[Char].

I have no idea where you got this idea. It's wrong. I'm guessing you've defined

```
type Poly a = [a]
```

and I'll go with that assumption.

```
instance (Num a, Show a) => Show (Poly a) where
```

This is wrong. `Poly` is a *type synonym*. You can only declare instances for proper first-class types (the application of a type constructor to zero or more type variables). You can fix this by using, instead,

```
newtype Poly a = Poly {getPoly :: [a]}
```

but then you need to wrap/unwrap the `Poly` data constructor as required. Once you've gotten this right, you'll probably see that the `Num` constraint you've given is unnecessary.

```
show p = ["" ++ form (p !! i) i | i <- [(length p)..0]]
```

There are a few problems. The big one is that this does not define a string (list of characters) but rather a list of strings. You can fix this, generally, by applying `concat` to the result. The second one is that `"" ++ anything` is just `anything`, because concatenating the empty list to another list doesn't do anything. The third problem is that you're trying to count down, but you've done it wrong. That notation only counts up. To count down, you have to show that you want to count down:

```
let lp = length p in [lp, (lp-1) .. 0]
```

The last thing I see immediately (some of these mistakes are repeated in the preceding two lines):

```
    | otherwise = e ++ "x^" ++ i ++ " + "
```

Now `i` is an `Int`, and `++` only works for lists. So that will not work. You need to first convert `i` to a string using `show`. `e` is of type `a`, and needs to be converted to a string using `show` as well.

Comment: I am attempting to complete the work in this assignment: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/hw/04-typeclasses.pdf, which is how i start out with `newtype Poly a = P [a]`, i will add this to the beginning, I got the form portion to work, now attempting to make the comprehension put it all together. thank you for your input, it has been helpful so far!

Comment: I will also edit the code to represent the changes made